# counting special characters in a user generated string

Tags: java, string, count

So I have this program that is supposed to to take any user generated string and display the amounts of white space, letters, numbers, and special characters. I do not want to duplicate a question. It seems to be a little more specific then talked about in other posts.

My error lies in the special characters. The specific error is return 0. I referenced stack overflow already in about every discussion they had on the matter. Which helped me form the special character method.

I have to keep the main method clear and call aforementioned methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput;
System.out.println("Please enter a string");
userInput = kbd.nextLine();

countletter(userInput);
countnumber(userInput);
countspecial(userInput);
countSpace(userInput);

}

public static void countletter(String userInput) {
    int countletter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (userInput.length() - 1); i++) {
        char location = userInput.charAt(i);
        boolean x = Character.isLetter(location);
        if (x) {
            countletter++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The number of Letters is: " + countletter);
}

public static void countnumber(String userInput) {
    int countnumber = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length() - 1; i++) {
        char location = userInput.charAt(i);
        boolean x = Character.isDigit(location);
        if (x) {
            countnumber++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The number of digits is: " + countnumber);
}

public static void countSpace(String userInput) {
    int countSpace = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length() - 1; i++) {
        char location = userInput.charAt(i);
        boolean x = Character.isWhitespace(location);
        if (x) {
            countSpace++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The number of white spaces is: " + countSpace);
}

public static void countspecial(String userInput) {

    if (userInput == null || userInput.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    int countSpecial = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
        if (userInput.substring(i, 1).matches("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]")) {
            countSpecial++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of special chars is: " + countSpecial++);
}
}
```

My initial attempt at countSpecial:

```
public static void countspecial(String userInput) {
   int countSpecial = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (userInput.length() - 1); i++) {
        if (userInput.substring(i, 1).matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]")) {
            countSpecial++;
        }

   }
   System.out.println("The number of special chars is: " + countSpecial++);
}
}
```

Where am I going wrong and why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your initial attemp you have problem with your substring
substring second parameter would be the index of your last character in the substring +1, and so you need to iterate until userInput.length() not userInput.length() -1.
And i dont know why would you increment the count after printing it , it actually does nothing but still makes no sense.

```
      public static void countspecial(String userInput) {
        if (userInput == null || userInput.trim().isEmpty()) {
          return ;
        }
        int countSpecial = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
           if (userInput.substring(i, i+1).matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]")) {
              countSpecial++;
           }

        }
        System.out.println("The number of special chars is: " + countSpecial);
        }
```

A better way instead of subtring you could use "(userInput.charAt(i)+"").matches".

But a better solution would be counting all the digits and letters and subtract their sum form the total length of the string , this would give you the number of special characters as it is not recommended to use regex for simple requirement like this.

Comment: the increment at the end was an accident I apologize. Your explanation was helpful to my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: if (userInput == null || userInput.trim().isEmpty()) {
          return ;

after setting the userInput to null what is trim().isEmpty()) actually doing, I am trying to understand this line of code. I haven't learned about .trim yet

Comment: trim() will remove the leading and trailing white spaces from the string

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, don't loop. Just replace all non-special chars with nothing and count the length:

```
int countSpecial = userInput.replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9\\s]", "").length();
```

You can apply this technique to all your character categories.

Comment: @AmerQarabsa what has substring to do with my answer (which works by the way)?

Comment: your second answer works, userInput.substring(i, 1).matches("[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]") this does not work

Answer (score -1):

Look at the javadocs for substring.

Some languages that use a flavor of substring(int beginIndex, int length) where beginIndex is where you start the substring and **length** is how many characters are in the substring.

Java uses substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) where beginIndex is where you start the substring and endIndex is the **position** of the ending character.

```
userInput.substring(i, 1);
```

Where i = 2 means you want to start the substring at index position 2 and end it at index position 1 and an exception is thrown.

Answer (score -1):

If you're defining anything other than a letter, digit or whitespace character to be "special" then you should really test for it in the same way as the other tests so you don't miss anything because of different definitions of what constitutes a letter or digit. Character.isLetter() will return true for any Unicode letter, for example, not just ASCII A-Z or a-z. For consistency you should write:

```
char c = userInput.charAt(i);
if (!Character.isDigit(c) && !Character.isLetter(c) && !Character.isWhiteSpace(c)) {
   countSpecial++;
}
```

But the problem in your original code is that the second parameter to String.substring() is the 'to' index, not a length. So if you were going to do with a regex it should be

```
if (userInput.substring(i, i+1).matches("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]")) {
   countSpecial++;
}
```

Is this a practical example or are you asking for help doing an assignment? :-)